# BeautifulSoup HTML except Tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="abc bg1">...</tr>
  <tr class="bg1">...</tr>
    <td> class="no">...</td>
    <td>sampletext</td>
    <td> class="title">...</td>
  <tr class="bg2">...</tr>
```

This sample code has 3 class 'abc bg1','bg1','bg2'
I want only 'bg1','bg2' tag
so I used `soup.select('tbody > tr.bg1 > td')`

This code results in 'abc bg1','bg1' tag children 'td'
How do I get the results I want?
And to 'bg1', I want to extract only text except for other Tags
ex):
sampletext <- only

Comment: Please format your question a bit better and explain properly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_str = """<tbody>
  <tr class="abc bg1">...</tr>
  <tr class="bg1">...</tr>
    <td> class="no">...</td>
    <td>sampletext</td>
    <td> class="title">...</td>
  <tr class="bg2">...</tr><tobdy>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_str)
bg1 = soup.findAll('tr', attrs= {'class':'bg1'})[1].text
```

if you use .findAll which finds all the attrs with that class name. It gives you an array; then simply call the array index for the tr you want.

**UPDATE** 
If you want element inside bg1; call another .find. Like this:
`sample_text = soup.findAll('td')[1].text` #This gives you "sample text".

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach to identify all the tags that have 'bg1' OR 'bg2', but NOT 'abc':

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '''<tbody>
    <tr class="abc bg1">...</tr>
    <tr class="bg1">...</tr>
        <td> class="no">...</td>
        <td>sampletext</td>
        <td> class="title">...</td>
    <tr class="bg2">...</tr>
</tbody>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, html.parser)


# We can look for all tags that are "tr" tags.
for tag in soup.find_all('tr'):

    # Each tag has attributes. We can reference the attrs dictionary
    #     using the attribute name as the key.
    if 'abc' in tag.attrs['class']:
        continue
    else:
        print(tag)

<tr class="bg1">...</tr>
<tr class="bg2">...</tr>
```